# yarn add <path-to-local-package> --offline does not install dependencies

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, offline-mode

I am working in a very restricted environment, which means I do not have any access to internet. I setup everything in order to import an Angular Template Project and install all the packages from an offline cache. I followed these steps:

**On the online machine**

1. configure `yarn-offline-mirror` with pruning to false (directory *X*)
2. create a new angular app with `ng new foo --skipInstall=true`
3. install the packages with `yarn (install)` in order to generate a *yarn.lock* and to store all the tgz-packages in directory *X*
4. delete *node_modules*
5. Whenever I need more packages, I use `npm-package-downloader` with the argument `-d` to download all the dependencies as tgz-files too and copy them to directory *X*

**On my offline machine**

6. I import the tgz-files from directory *X* and put them in the same location
7. I configure `yarn-offline-mirror` like on my online machine
8. I Import the angular template and install the needed packages with `yarn clean cache` followed by `yarn --offline`

As long all the tgz-packages are on my offline machine, this works like a charm (because of *yarn.lock*).

**My Problem**

I want to add further packages on my offline machine. The packages are present in the offline mirror, because I copied them onto the machine. When I run

```
yarn clean cache
yarn add <absolute-path-to-tgz-package> --offline
```

two possible scenarios arise:

1. The package has no dependencies, in which case it works as intended
2. The package has dependencies: in this case, follwing error gets thrown for each "missing" dependency (*package-name* and *package-version* are placeholders):

> Couldn't find any versions for "package-name" that matches
>   "package-version" in our cache. This is usually caused by a missing
>   entry in the lockfile, running Yarn without the --offline flag may
>   help fix the issue.

As far as I understand, yarn needs somehow to know, which dependencies a package requires. But it has to know, otherwise it couldn't throw this specific error. So my question is, how can I force yarn to look for dependencies in directory *X* too? The packages are there, since I download them with the respective dependencies. And obviously I am not supposed to manually edit *yarn.lock*. The docs for yarn add do not list such an option (as a matter of fact, it does not even list the `--offline` flag)